# How to invite a few relevant users to a chat room?

Tags: support, chat

I want to invite a few select people to a chatroom, but I can't find the right place to "invite".

Chatroom: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83301/jug-meetup-western-australia

I read https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq but I don't see:

> If you need to invite someone to your room, do it from the user's chat profile page or from the user card that pops up when you click on their avatar in a chat room.

Answer (score 1):

The user must already be on the Chat Exchange site.

Here you can see a list of all users: https://chat.stackexchange.com/users

1. Select a user
2. Select a room (just below their profile stats)
3. Click "Invite this user to"